# How to show a float with no decimals

Tags: unity, javascript, gui

I want to show the current health and stamina of the player using GUI.Label. All is working fine however it shows the values with decimals to the millionth (example: http://gfycat.com/SkeletalSinfulKouprey). How would I go about showing only the whole number?

My code:

```
 var cur_stamina : float; 
    var cur_health : float;

    var staminaRegenRate : float = 5;
    var healthRegenRate : float = 1;

    //regen
    if(cur_stamina < max_stamina){
        cur_stamina += staminaRegenRate * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if(cur_health < max_health){
        cur_health += healthRegenRate * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    function OnGUI(){
        GUI.Label(Rect(1,1,100,20), "Health: " +cur_health);
        GUI.Label(Rect(1,15,1000,20), "Stamina: " +cur_stamina);
        GUI.Label(Rect(1,30,100,20), "Ammo: " +cur_ammo);
    }
```

Comment: Convert it to an integer?

Comment: @Ben then the regen doesn't work

Comment: Convert it to an integer just before you send it to GUI.Label. Don't convert the actual variable, create a temporary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget that every object in .NET has a `ToString()` method. Many of the built-in value types accept an optional formatting argument; numeric types in particular are easy to format with [standard formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) or [custom formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

For example, instead of just passing `cur_health`, you could pass `cur_health.ToString("n0")`.

For the specific question, you could also truncate using [Mathf.FloorToInt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bitwise OR to just truncate:

```
GUI.Label(Rect(1,1,100,20), "Health: " +cur_health | 0);
```

Or, if you care about accuracy, you can use Unity's API to round it:

```
GUI.Label(Rect(1,1,100,20), "Health: " Mathf.Round(+cur_health));
```